# Mysql - Manipulating data from a column into rows

Tags: mysql

Please forgive my lack of knowledge, I have been given the chance to progress within work by learning mysql and databases but was given a task of thinking of a project I could work on that would improve things for my colleagues.

What I hope to do is supply them the data in a more usable format.

What I would like to know is there a way that I can take the data that is pulled from the company database in a couple of columns with the same date and time on each row and manipulate it so it displays across several columns.

Sorry my description isn't the best but I hope that the layout below will give a clearer indication of what I'm hoping to do (the bold is the column headings).

Original layout:

```
date    time    column 1  column 2 
date 1  time 1  data a    data b            
date 1  time 1  data c    data d            
date 1  time 1  data e    data f
```

Desired Layout:

```
date    time    column 1  column 2  column 3  column 4  column 5
date 1  time 1  data a    data b    data c    data e    data f
```

I'm just hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction of what to research - my Google searches have not come up with anything I can use but there again I'm probably not asking the right worded question.

Again apologies for my ignorance but as name suggests I am a complete newbie.

Comment: u have missed data d by mistakenly or want to exclude it if want to exclude it then on which logic basis.

Comment: On what criteria can the system identify whether the actual row should be inserted into which column-set (`column 1` and `column 2` or `column 3` and `column 4` etc.)? Only by row order? Anyways, this would be much more convenient to solve by a small script in PHP or Perl or another programming language than in pure SQL.